# In cypress - how do I store elements in an array and then compare the same elements to each other?

Tags: arrays, loops, compare, cypress

So I have a list of elements on a webpage which have **dates in String or text format**.
I want to extract them and split them into three - **dd, mm and yyyy** sections.
Then, I must concat them, in this order - **yyyy+mm+dd** so I can always determine whether the **dates are sorted**.

For example let's say the list of dates I extract is:

```
07/20/2021
07/19/2021
06/23/2021
06/22/2021
05/18/2020
```

So I split them using substring() so they look like:

```
dd = ["20", "19", "23", "22", "18"]
mm = ["07", "07", "06", "06", "05"]
yyyy = ["2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2020"]
```

Then I concat them:

```
dates = ["20210720", "20210719", "20210623", "20210622", "20200518"]
```

However, I am using Cypress for automation; and post Cypress 7.4 I guess I am not able to iterate over an array using a for loop, whenever I try doing this:

```
let dates = cy.get('<locator string>');

for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

    <Iterate and compare the dates>

}
```

**It would be immensely helpful to just be able to do this.**

However I am not able to. So, if there's another way, like using:

```
cy.get(<locator string>).then($el)
```

or

```
cy.get(<locator string>).each($el)
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the jQuery elements to an array and `.map()` to iterate and convert them (one option of many)

```js
cy.get('<locator string>').then($dateEls => { 

  const dateStrings = [...$dateEls].map(el => el.innerText)  // convert els to texts
  const isoDates = dateStrings.map(dateString => {           // convert format
    const [mm, dd, yyyy] = dateString.split('/')             // destructure
    return `${yyyy}${mm}${dd}`
  })
  isoDates.sort().reverse()                                  // sort descending
  return isoDates
})
.should('deep.eq', ["20210720", "20210719", "20210623", "20210622", "20200518"])
.should(dates => {
  const [maxDate, ...otherDates] = dates             // destructure list head and tail
  otherDates.forEach(date => {
    expect(+date).to.be.lt(+maxDate))                // "+" converts to numeric
  })
})
```

If the elements are `<input>` you would extract the date text from `el.value` instead of `el.innerText`

**Note** `[...$dateEls]` converts the array-like object into a true JavaScript array using the spread operator.

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome. Is there a way I could assert that every other element in isoDates is less than the max isoDate?

I tried `to.be.at.most` but it just compares the element with itself

Comment: I think you can chain another `.should()` with a callback, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this piece of code:

```
static verifySortingByNewest() {
    cy.get('<locator-string>').each(($el) => {
         var latest = $el.first().text().substring(6, 9).concat($el.first().text().substring(0, 1)).concat($el.first().text().substring(3, 4));
         cy.log(latest);
         var current = $el.text().substring(6, 9).concat($el.text().substring(0, 1)).concat($el.text().substring(3, 4));
         cy.log(current);

         expect(Number(current)).to.be.at.most(Number(latest));
    });
}
```

Which results in the following assertions:

[image: Image displays assertions resulting from the code above]

Given that my array of elements is always sorted descending due to an app filter, how do I make latest to always point at the first element?